# Audio not playing in VLC for one specific video only

Tags: audio, vlc-media-player, mp4

Playing a specific `.mp4` file in VLC plays the video fine, but not the audio. According to VLC's codec information the audio codec is `mp4a`. But the statistics say decoded 0 blocks and played 0 buffers. Both the video and the audio play fine in Avidemux and SMPlayer.

Comment: VLC works with its own internal set of codecs. Most of the times it's an advantage for unusual, "exotic", codecs but occasionally it's the other way around.